# AllItems customization

Tags: sharepoint-server, caml-query, list-definition, custom-schema

I have a custom list definition where I have defined a view with `BaseViewID = 1` (AllItems.aspx)

```
  <View BaseViewID="1" Type="HTML" WebPartZoneID="Main" DisplayName="$Resources:core,objectiv_schema_mwsidcamlidC24;" DefaultView="TRUE" MobileView="TRUE" MobileDefaultView="TRUE" SetupPath="pages\viewpage.aspx" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/generic.png" Url="AllItems.aspx">
    <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
    <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
    <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
    <ViewFields>
      <FieldRef Name="Attachments"></FieldRef>
      <FieldRef Name="LinkTitle"></FieldRef>
      <FieldRef Name="Field1"></FieldRef>
      <FieldRef Name="Field2"></FieldRef>
      <FieldRef Name="Field3"></FieldRef>
    </ViewFields>
    <Query>
      <OrderBy>
        <FieldRef Name="ID"></FieldRef>
      </OrderBy>
    </Query>
    <ParameterBindings>
      <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_LIST)" />
      <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_DEFAULT)" />
    </ParameterBindings>
  </View>
```

I would like to customize this view by adding a query element.
*The query must return only items posted by users belonging to the group of the current user.*

For example: user1 and user 2 are part of Group A while user 3 is part of Group B. If every user add an item both user1 and user 2 see two items while user3 only see one item.

Is it possible to define a query to achieve this result? if not, what are the options I can investigate?

Thanks very much

**EDIT**

I have followed the steps described in [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/80aa4ad9-3a8c-4f44-a595-7200976893e5/sharepoint-list-items-filter-by-user-groups?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious) but unfortunately does not work

Comment: Reread your question, and realized I misunderstood it the first time.  My answer will not work.  I believe something custom will need to be done.  Are you able to use custom solutions?

Comment: Yes. It depends what do you mean by custom solution. Actually I have a Visual studio project which create a WSP. I also have a custom list definition inside a custom site definition

Comment: You can do a less code intensive solution, creating a view per group, using the `<Membership>` element in CAML.  Or you can do an App (or wsp, if you don't mind using deprecated solutions).